# How can I "reclaim" the MX control of domain where former employee configured Gmail to handle mail?

Tags: dns, gmail, mx

A former employee had configured Gmail to handle their work email (an address that is @ an alias—herein called "example.com"—for our primary domain). The employee left and is not cooperative. I tried to forward all email for that domain to another address, but get the message that "*Forwarding rules conflict with other DNS records*." When I use Terminal to get MX records for that domain (i.e., "`$ host -t mx example.com`"), the response is that "`example.com mail is handled by 5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com`" (and 4 other Google servers)
How can I "reclaim" the MX control for that domain?

Comment: I'm not sure how you tried to "forward" the emails.  It shouldn't be a DNS setting to do that, you'd have to do that on your mail server (in other words a setting in Google.)

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is find where DNS is hosted, this might be revealed by the nameservers e.g. ns1.hostingexample.com or ns1.domainseller.com  You say it is a `.com` so try https://lookup.icann.org/en

Once you have that, log into that place and you should have a DNS editor of some sort.  If it is a cPanel server, look for the `zone editor`.

In the DNS zone editor you should have access to the MX records.  If it were me, I would change the MX Record to mail.example.com and then make sure there is an A Record for mail.example.com pointing to the IP address of your mail server.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know where you want email to actually go. If not, figure that out first.

Every primary domain (domain.tld) is registered with one of the official registrars.  There are a number of them, depending on the tld (top level domain).  Among the information managed by the registrar are the "name servers" for the domain. These name servers are where the DNS information for the domain is managed.  Included in the DNS information is the MX records, which specify the mail servers handling email for the domain.

The easiest way to find this information out is to use [MXToolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/), which is an awesome tool. Go there and enter the domain.  I will use StackExchange for reference.

[image: MXLookup Home Page]

It tells you the MX records.  StackExchange uses Google as well. You can then use their DNS Lookup tool to get what you need.

[image: Change to DNS Lookup]

[image]

In this case, StackExchange uses Amazon Route 53 for DNS.  If you do the same thing for your domain, you should be able to see who provides your DNS. Whoever that is, you need to get access to their management console and update the MX records for your domain.

*NOTE - if your domain email is being sent to Google, there is a Google Workspace console somewhere for your domain, and you may well be paying for the Workspace domain. You may want to figure out how to get access to that console.  Start with Google support to figure that out.*